# Modeling microcomputer registers in memory?

Tags: c++, emulation, intel-8080

As a little side project I've been creating an older microcomputer CPU emulator, mostly based off the 8080's architecture. Its 8-bit general purpose registers can ([according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080#Registers))  be used "as three 16-bit register pairs," as well as the normal 8-bit mode. And here's my problem.

My first try at modelling this was individual named bytes and shorts, which worked fine until I re-read the specs page and found that the 16-bit registers aren't actually their own thing. Oops.

What I'm trying now is an array of bytes, with one location for each 8-bit register, and two locations reserved for the stack/instruction pointers. This works very well and good for the 8-bit registers, and it's a lot less of a hassle to manage, but I don't actually know how to convert two bytes to a short in memory. Is that even possible? If not, do you have any suggestions on how else to do this?

Comment: Consider using a union. Or if you want to work directly with the memory representation, a pointer.

Comment: Er, how would I go about making a pointer that points to two variables of a different type? I'm still learning C++ wizardry.

Comment: Basically you would have two pointers of different type with the same memory address.  I'm not sure that C++ has much to recommend it for this task.  It would be trivial in C however, in no small part because of the similarities between the programming model nakedly exposed in C and the sort of hardware architecture you are trying to emulate.  Granted, the pointer approach somewhat requires that your emulated and host architectures have the same endianness... which at the present instant in time is highly likely.

Answer (score -1):

Solved via casting the address of the first byte in the 16-bit register to a void pointer, and back to a short. Not very type-safe, but hey, it works. Apparently I was just googling the wrong things.

Comment: A traditional concept of type safety is going to start to work against you here, as in building an emulator, you need to reproduce the fact that the machine will interpret the same bits in a variety of ways depending on the instruction being executed.  You are already aware of the width difference.  But also look out for the signed/unsigned one.  And not all ALU operations will have direct C/C++ counterparts - for example, you have rotates as well as shifts.  And then there is the carry bit - which might or might not be included in those.

Comment: This is not type-safe enough to be legal in C++, sorry. And it would break if you tried to run the program on a big-endian machine.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have to say I don't really have any experience with unions, but I might revisit this once the prototype's up and running and polish it a bit. I've made sure everything is unsigned as well, using unsigned chars and uint16_t's for 8/16-bit things, to be specific. And I know this is a terrible programming practice, but 'legal' or 'working'?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a `struct` of two `uint8_t`s that is also accessible as a `uint16_t` by doing this:

```
union Register
{
    uint16_t word;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t lo, hi;
    } byte;
};
```

This way, if you have a value in scope `Register r`, then `r.word` will access the contents as a single 16-bit value, and `r.byte.lo` and `r.byte.hi` will access the first and the second 8-bit byte. (The first one is `lo` because the Intel 8080 is a [little-endian architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian).)

Comment: To the downvoter: is my answer based on a misunderstanding of OP's question?